# Visual Studio 2008 Debugging of SQL Server 2005 SP on Remote Host

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I am using VS 2008 and trying to step into a stored procedure on a SQL Server 2005 database. I bring up Server Explorer, double-click on the procedure. It comes up in the text window. I set a break point in it, right click and select "Step into stored procedure". It comes back with "canceled by user". MSVSCOM.exe is running on the SQL Server host and I can connect to remote processes on SQL Server host. What's interesting about this is I can "Step Into a Stored Procedure" if I first attached to a remote process on the SQL Server Host. However, once that process is closed and/or I detach I get the infamous "Canceled by User" message. I've found numerous postings on this (e.g., [1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/b6e670a7-68ba-453c-8d05-882cf0990e81)), but no solid explanation of what's wrong.

Anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is by design.  It's the way the debugger works.  If you are debugging an unmanaged process on the same machine you also have to attach the process first.